# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 25, 25, 1]

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I am trying to use conv1D but getting that error.
My dataset's is batched and has a shape of [None, 25, 25, 1]
I am using input_shape=(25,25)
I am not able to figure out what should I change so I can get it to work.

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(25,25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the shape of my dataset using:

```
tf.reshape(data, [25, 25])
```

Comment: where did you use this code? i am getting the same error

Comment: I reshaped the dataset I use to train the model. you can use `data = tf.reshape(data, [25, 25])`

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 30, 3), found shape=(None, 30, 30, 4)
I am not able to figure out what should i change

Comment: I think it is because you are using 2 different shapes: (30, 30, 3) and (30, 30, 4).